# Factor $x^{80} - 1$ over $F_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Factor $x^{80} - 1$ over $F_3$

---

Effort

Factor $x^{80} - 1$ over $F_3$

$$\begin{aligned}
x^{40}-1&=(x^{20}+1)(x^{20}-1)
     \\&=(x^{20}+1)(x^{10}+1)(x^{10}-1     )
     \\&=(x^{20}+1)(x^{10}+1)(x^{5}+1     )(x^{5}-1     )
\end{aligned} $$

since we are in $F_3$ , $(x^{20}+1),(x^{10}+1),(x^{5}+1 )$ are factorable by $(x-2)$ and $x^5-1$ by $x-1$

so $$x^5-1= (x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1) $$
 what computer is saying that it factors to

```
(x + 1) * (x + 2) * (x^2 + 1) * (x^2 + x + 2) * (x^2 + 2*x + 2) * (x^4 +
x + 2) * (x^4 + 2*x + 2) * (x^4 + x^2 + 2) * (x^4 + x^2 + x + 1) * (x^4
+ x^2 + 2*x + 1) * (x^4 + 2*x^2 + 2) * (x^4 + x^3 + 2) * (x^4 + x^3 +
2*x + 1) * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1) * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) * (x^4 +
x^3 + x^2 + 2*x + 2) * (x^4 + x^3 + 2*x^2 + 2*x + 2) * (x^4 + 2*x^3 + 2)
* (x^4 + 2*x^3 + x + 1) * (x^4 + 2*x^3 + x^2 + 1) * (x^4 + 2*x^3 + x^2 +
x + 2) * (x^4 + 2*x^3 + x^2 + 2*x + 1) * (x^4 + 2*x^3 + 2*x^2 + x + 2)
```

---

Been trying to find examples. I do not see the factors just how one would hypothetically find them. I think finding them takes a lot of work for a human. **maybe it factors to something simple,beautiful and elegant but it does not seems to be the case unless I am wrong.**

Comment: isn't $x^{80} = x^2$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Comment: @gt6989b No. $x^{80}$ and $x^2$ are different elements of $\Bbb F_3[x]$, even if $x^{80}=x^2$ for all $\in \Bbb F_3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x^{81}-x = x(x^{80}-1)$. $81 = 3^4$, so $x^{81}-x$ factors into all the irreducible polynomials of degree $1,2,4$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$. So we could do this by listing polynomials of degrees $1,2,4$ and discovering which are irreducible.